# Kodak Hero 5.1 Scanner Permissions on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, permissions, scanner

I have a Hero 5.1 AIO Printer/Scanner and use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Printer works fine but I can only use scanner in sudo mode. I have added my username by sudo adduser les scanner but still no luck.

sudo scanimage -L outputs :- device `kodakaio:libusb:001:005' is a Kodak KODAK HERO 5.1 AiO flatbed scanner

scanimage -L outputs :- No scanners were identified.

Can someone suggest a workaround please? It will need to be simply explained. I am new to Linux having just moved from Windows XP.

Thanks
Les

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer at  help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingScannerPermissions

Added lines to /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules

'# Kodak Hero 5.1'

ATTRS{idVendor}=="040a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4064", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

Scanner works fine now as a user.